# Как посчитать время за которое человек ввёл переменную?

Tags: python

Скажите пожалуйста - как посчитать время за которое человек ввёл переменную:

```py
a = int(input())
```

Мне надо посчитать за какое время кто-то ввёл переменную `a`.
Будет лучше если код будет маленький и понятный (я начинающий программист).
Заранее спасибо!)

Comment: В каждом языке есть специальные библиотеки, измеряющие время. Как только пользователю будет предложен ввод, сразу сохраняем текущее время в переменную следующей же строкой в коде. Как только ввод осуществлен - следующей же строкой опять сохраняем уже новое текущее время во вторую переменную и затем из второй переменной вычитаем первую.

Comment: Немного перепутал: в первую переменную время должно быть сохранено **до** того, как пользователю будет предложен ввод, а не после. То есть прям предыдущей строкой.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import time

# Зафиксируйте время начала ввода
start_time = time.time()

# Пользователь вводит переменную
a = int(input("Введите значение переменной a: "))

# Зафиксируйте время окончания ввода
end_time = time.time()

# Вычислите время, затраченное на ввод
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time

# Выведите результат
print(f"Человек ввел переменную a за {elapsed_time:.2f} секунд.")
```

Comment: Отдельно лайк за отличные комментарии в коде )

Comment: спасибо - всё работает!)

Answer (score -2):

На Java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VariablePeriod {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String variable = null;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите значение переменной");
        long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
        variable = scanner.next();
        long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Значение переменной - " + variable);
        System.out.println("Переменная введена за " + (after - before) + " миллисекунд");
        scanner.close();
        
    }

}
```

Comment: А можно узнать за что минусы, пожалуйста? Код же рабочий.

Comment: @Дмитрий вопрос то про питон а не про Java! Ж)

Comment: Человек не просил код конкретно на питоне. Это во-первых. Во-вторых метка про питон появилась не сразу. Автор сказал, что его все устраивает.